# how to parse xml from an http-triggered logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

**How do I extract the *content* of my request that's been received inside of the logic app?**

I've got a regular http-triggered logic app, like so:

[image]

I'm sending it a `POST` request through postman like so:

[image]

```
{
    "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "$content": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><cases><file-path>yes</file-path></cases>"
}
```

I'm attempting to extract the `$content` payload:

```
"@{string(xml(string(triggerBody()?['content'])))}"
```

The issue I am getting is:

[image]

**How do I extract the *content* of my request that's been received inside of the logic app?**

Here's the entire *initialize variable* step:

```
    "Initialize_variable": {
        "inputs": {
            "variables": [
                {
                    "name": "contentOfRequest",
                    "type": "String",
                    "value": "@{string(xml(string(triggerBody()?['content'])))}"
                }
            ]
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause the request body is string, it doesn't support select property. so you need parse it Json format firstly, then you will be able to select `$content`.

[image]

About how to get the Json Schema, just click the `Use sample payload to generate schema` in the `Parse Json` action and paste your Json data, then click the done.

And then extract the `$content` value with `body('Parse_JSON')?['$content']`, in this way you will get the content value.

[image]